# Very Basic Node Removal in Swift

Tags: swift, skspritenode, removechild

I found some other questions about node removal in swift, but none of them seemed to be quite relevant to my issue.

I just want to do a basic node removal, for example:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent){

let covernode1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "tester")

covernode1.position = CGPointMake(100.0, 600.0)

for touch: AnyObject in touches {

if self.nodeAtPoint(location) == self.fake {

button1++
button2++
}

if(button1 == 1 && button2 == 1){

addChild(covernode1)

}

if(button1 == 2 && button2 == 2){
//THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO REMOVE THE NODE
}
```

I have tried

```
covernode1.removeFromParent()
```

but to no avail.

The code runs the addChild part fine, but removal seems to be a problem. I even tried just changing the position of the node so it's off screen, with something like

```
covernode1.position = CGPointMake(-100.0, -600.0)
```

This did not work either.

Thank you.

Comment: Try using println() to find out where in the code the issue is. My guess is that `if(button1 == 2 && button2 == 2){
//THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO REMOVE THE NODE
}` isnt even running

Comment: I tried printing text in the console as you're suggesting and the "if statement" is running correctly and does print out text in the console.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to comment on your original question, so this may not be an "answer" per se, but I'll try and diagnose what I think is going on, and hopefully you can clear up some points for me.

The `covernode1` that you are trying to remove from the parent view in your if statement may be a different node than the one you added to the view when you called `addChild(covernode1)`

I think this is the case because when you say you are using `covernode1.position = CGPointMake(-100.0, -600.0)` and it still does not work, that makes me think that is a completely different SKNode object.

Instead, try declaring `covernode1` outside of the function as a class variable.  That way, when you actually instantiate it and refer to it in the function, it is grabbing the correct node you are looking for.  Let me know if any of this helps.  I'll edit the answer when I know a bit more from your response.

Also, are your `button1` and `button2` vars originally set to 1?

EDIT: Another question: Are you receiving any error when calling `.removeFromParent()` or is just "not doing anything"?

Comment: Changing the position of `covernode1` was just to try to make it disappear. (The point of me adding that in was just to point out that I want 'covernode1' to disappear by any means). I am not sure why it would be a different node, could you explain why if possible? My `button1` and `button2` are originally set to 0. And no, I am not receiving an error just nothing is happening.

Comment: Right, I know you were trying to make a temporary fix.  So I'm going to edit my answer based on what I think may be happening.  Let me know if any of it works and we can go from there.

Comment: I tried declaring the covernode as a class variable and I got a SIGABRT error: "Attempt to add a SKNode which already has a parent"

Comment: Ah okay, so one more clarification that could help: This "Covernode", should there only ever be one instance of it in the SKScene? Or are you purposefully trying to make multiple instances of it?  I know the error you are getting and I think I have a fix, just let me know about that last question.

Comment: This is the situation: I have a sprite on the screen that has a few characteristics that aren't really of any relevance to the covernode issue. I have six other SKNodes that change certain characteristics of the Sprite and the screen etc... These are present above the area in which the original sprite operates. If the user clicks two of these SKNodes that change certain characteristics, I want the other four nodes to be covered up and not usable (the user can have two sprite characteristic altering sprites on at one time).

Answer (score 0):

One simple thing you could do (kind of cheating but it will work) is to hide the node using

```
covernode1.hidden = true
```

**Note**

Also make sure the `if` statement actually runs because I don't know why the things you tried should not work. To test that, place a `println("log")` in the `if` block.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work. I tested the conditional 'if statement' by printing out text in the console, and it is running. There is another node under 'covernode' could that be part of the problem?

Comment: What do you mean with "under"? In sense of `.zPosition` or is it a child of the same view?

Comment: In the sense of position, the covernode is covering another SKNode that acts on a sprite.

Comment: Why don't you hide that one too?

Answer (score 0):

From button1 and button2, I think you are trying to do this: On the first click, you add a SKNode. On the second click, you want to remove the SKNode.
Thus on the second click your `let covernode1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "tester")` is a different instance although it has the same variable name ! Thus the instance on the second click is not removable since it was not added to anything.

Try this,

```
if(button1 == 1 && button2 == 1){
    addChild(covernode1)
    self.tempChildCount = count(self.children) //tempChildCount is an integer
}

if(button1 == 2 && button2 == 2){
    let childNode = self.children[self.tempChildCount - 1 ] as! SKNode
    self.removeChildrenInArray([childNode])
}
```